# Counting elements of an array using a recursive function in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am going through the grokking algorithms book and trying to wrap my head around recursion. One of the challenges in the book is to "Write a recursive function to count the number of items in a list.". I came up with the following code, which works:

```js
function recursiveArrayCount(arr, count) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    arr.pop();
    return count + recursiveArrayCount(arr, count);
  }
}

let myArray = [1, 10, 23, 11, 4, 48, 88];
console.log(recursiveArrayCount(myArray, 1));
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this in javascript? In particular, I don't like having to seed the value of count with the initial '1' - but I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: *"is there a better way to do this in javascript"*: yes. This is not something you should use recursion for. For long arrays you will get a stack overflow error. Besides, your function is mutating the array with `pop`. That is not nice for the caller of your function, who will find after the call that their array has been destroyed. It is also strange to see code that attempts to count entries in an array without using the `length` property (which is the straightforward solution of course), but then *still* uses that property.

Comment: I agree with what trincot said in his comment. Using length property in a function that should calculate the length of the array without using the length property is strange.

Comment: I agree you would never do this in practice, it was just meant as an exercise in understanding recursion. I also agree that using arr.length was a poor choice given the role of the function.

Changing it to if (arr == '') works and makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a second argument at all:

```js
function recursiveArrayCount(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + recursiveArrayCount(arr.slice(1));
}
```

Comment: I also like using `slice` rather than modifying the original array. Another approach that dosen't require copying the array *or* modifying it is to change the `if`: `if (arr.length <= count) { return count; }`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for - simple and eloquent.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but using `arr.length` is sort of a cheat... there'd be no reason to do counting if we can just access the `length` property...

Comment: @Thank you, that was my mistake. if (arr == '') also works and makes more sense given the functions role.

Comment: @Thankyou - Yeah, well, I figured it was allowed given the OP was doing it...and since there's (almost) no other way to check whether you've reached the end of an array. :-)

Comment: @crims0n - `if (arr == "")` is also true for an array with a single entry that's a blank string. There's no way to tell if a JavaScript array is empty (or that you've reached the end of it) without using `length` or a loop from `0` through `< Math.pow(2, 32) - 1` repeatedly calling `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder unless array is sparse, `if (!arr.hasOwnProperty(count)) { return count; }` should work.

Comment: @Yousaf - Right, but that's a massive caveat, which is kind of my point. :-)

Comment: If you were insistent on not checking the length property, you could determine if the array is empty via `arr.every(v => false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a proper tail call by eliminating any reference to variables that would be needed *after* the recursive call returns.

```js
function recursiveArrayCount(arr) {
  return _recursiveCount(arr, 0);

  function _recursiveCount(arr, count) {
    return arr.length == 0 ? count : _recursiveCount(arr.slice(1), count + 1);
  }
}

let myArray = [1, 10, 23, 11, 4, 48, 88];
console.log(recursiveArrayCount(myArray));
```

This makes it more likely to be optimized by reusing stack space.

Also, I used a nested function for the recursion, which ensures that the `count` is properly initialized.

---

You could also get a little fancy with the inner function, like this:

```js
function recursiveArrayCount(arr) {
  return (function _recursiveCount(arr, count) {
    return arr.length == 0 ? count : _recursiveCount(arr.slice(1), count + 1);
  })(arr, 0);
}

let myArray = [1, 10, 23, 11, 4, 48, 88];
console.log(recursiveArrayCount(myArray));
```

It's a recursively invoked IIFE.